# How do I select and join from a single table with 2 unique IDs based on one ID and concatenate the options?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, max, case, where-clause

I don't have much experience with SQL so forgive me if it is a simple answer...

I am working on a personal project in Python and I am using sqlite3. I currently have a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (id text, username text, score integer, UNIQUE(id,username))
```

where the idea is two users can score the same ID differently, and also the same user can score multiple ID's.

| ID | Username | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 5 |
| 1 | User2 | 7 |
| 1 | User3 | 10 |
| 2 | User1 | 6 |
| 2 | User2 | 2 |

How to I select to find common ID's among users as well as their scores? Is there a select command I can string up to return something like this? (i.e. common between users User1 and User2)

| ID | Score User1 | Score User2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'User1' THEN score END) ScoreUser1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'User2' THEN score END) ScoreUser2
FROM tablename
WHERE username IN ('User1', 'User2')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ea7a8fe88ebd0326812e173bd2c7a13e).